# preg_replace -- umlauts not processed on Server

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7, preg-replace, diacritics

I have written a small function to replace umlauts and other special german charackters in a string.

The whole thing looks like that:

```
function replace_german_chars($str)
{
  return preg_replace(
    array("/\s+/", "@\x{00e4}@u", "@\x{00fc}@u", "@\x{00f6}@u", "@\x{00df}@u"),  
    array("-", "ae", "ue", "oe", "ss"), 
    $str);
}
```

That code is mainly influenced by [this](http://php.net/manual/de/normalizer.normalize.php#92592) comment in the php manual.

However, it works as it should on my localhost (Mac OSX Yosmite), but not on the server. The function above just replaces the special chars with nothing.

Any Idea?

**[UPDATE]**

After gaining enough permission I could manage to insert the suggested »ini_sets«. Some of them seem to »survive« throughout the application life-cycle, some not. The use of `mb_convert_encoding` before this settings worked, but does not afterwards and returns `?` for all the matches.

I really do not get the point of that. I is somehow strange, since it seems that there are actually multiple encodings in play, even if Drupal states that it internally handles everything in utf-8.

**[UPDATE #2]**

The journey goes on, setting `mbstring.http_output=UTF-8` makes Drupal say: "Disable that"! Right now, I have no real Idea where all that might come from, so I dicided to post the http header of the page:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2015 10:07:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Language: de
Link: </node/10>; rel="shortlink",</startseite>; rel="canonical"
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
```

Next to this, there is another thing that might the cause of the problem: The overall collation setting of the Database Server within `phpMyAdmin`. To keep things clear, here is an Image of that:

[image]

The Database Server itself is configured to use `UTF-8`

Comment: Try converting `$str` to utf-8 with `mb_convert_encoding()` before replacing, like this http://rextester.com/UDKYJ53070

Comment: THANKS A LOT! The `mb_convert_encoding()` seems to make it!

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace()` is expecting a `utf-8` encoded string. It seems like you have set a different default encoding. Then, you need to convert `$str`:

> [**string mb_convert_encoding** ( string `$str` , string `$to_encoding` [, mixed `$from_encoding` = `mb_internal_encoding()` ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)
>
> Converts the character encoding of string `str` to `to_encoding` from optionally `from_encoding`.

This function gets the internal character encoding as `from_encoding` by default. If it's not detected by default, set your encoding from one of the [supported encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php).

---

**Code**

```
function replace_german_chars($str)
{
  return preg_replace(
    array("/\s+/", "@\x{00e4}@u", "@\x{00fc}@u", "@\x{00f6}@u", "@\x{00df}@u"),  
    array("-", "ae", "ue", "oe", "ss"), 
    mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8') );
}
```

<kbd>[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/UDKYJ53070)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The most probable solution to your question is unicode content.

You should use the following syntax in Apache configuration (in httpd.conf or .htaccess)

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

And in your php.ini set below Configuration

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.func_overload=6
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds somehow reasonable. The problem is that I cannot modify the php.ini and the server seams to be nginx. :)

Comment: If you can use `ini_set()` then somehow you will come to know if the problem is related to that or not?

Comment: I've already tried, but since that is a drupal 7 site I am not sure if the setting are overriden somewhere again.  Is there anyway I can verify that the ini-settings are correct?

Comment: you can use `ini_get()` or `ini_get_all()` to verify the runtime PHP ini configuration. 
@Mariano has given perfect solution so as per me you may try that one.

Comment: @philipp Did you got any solution?